# Default phing log file location?

Tags: php, logging, migration, phing

I am debugging a phing-based workflow and wish to see errors in detail. (An error is being sent to standard output when I run my phing-based migration script, but it is fairly minimal.)

The main file that seems to be prescribing phing behaviors is called migrate.xml, and I have checked in that file for any mention of the string "log" with no results. So I assume that phing is logging to whatever location it logs to by default. So far, I have looked in /var/log and found no file containing the string "phing."

So my question is this: **Is there a default location for phing logs?** A quick perusal of Google and the phing documentation has so far found nothing, but I'd be quite happy if it turned out that I missed something, in which case maybe this question helps someone else. A secondary question if we can't answer the main question might be "how might one find the place where phing is sending log output?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found some output related to phing in my default `php.log` file, living in the `/var/log` directory.

But this probably isn't everything I was looking for. Phing includes a `-logfile` option, which leads me to believe it can log more than what goes to the PHP log by default.

====

**Edit:** I did some poking around over the weekend, and it looks like the `-logfile` argument just causes the output that would normally go to stdout to be instead rerouted to a file. So it appears there's no "default log location" for Phing, beyond what goes to the standard PHP error log.

A slight consolation: I found that in addition to the `-verbose` command line argument -- which I had known about -- there's also a `-debug` argument that can give some additional information. So maybe that information helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Phing 2.10.0](https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/blob/b1b6d0753662045d69c71b4ae9eadd4b8fa661db/CHANGELOG.md#feb-9-2015---phing-2100) you could also use the [`record`](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/chunkhtml/RecordTask.html) task to define your own file based logging workflow.

```
    <!-- INIT -->
    <record name="verbose.log" loglevel="verbose" append="true" emacsmode="true"/>
    <!-- START -->
    <record name="verbose.log" action="start"/>
    <!-- STOP -->
    <record name="verbose.log" action="stop"/>
```